# Angular 6: Not able to inject a service in dynamic component using JIT compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to inject a service in my dynamic component that I am creating but when I try to inject a service I get an error. I am able to inject the service in all the other components which used AOT but not when I am using JIT. Here is the code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable
export class ApplicantSvc
{
 name:string;  
}

private createComponentFromRaw(template: string){

  const tmpCmp = Component({ template })(class {

    constructor(private app :ApplicantSvc){}

  });

  // Now, also create a dynamic module.
  const tmpModule = NgModule({
    declarations: [tmpCmp],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    providers: [ApplicantSvc],

  })(class {});


  this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      this.cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);
      this.cmpRef.instance.name = 'my-dynamic-component';
      this.vc.insert(this.cmpRef.hostView);
    });
}
```

In the above code I have added ApplicantSvc for providers in dynamic module and then injected in dynamic component constructor but whenever I try to do that I get an error

> ERROR Error: Can't resolve all parameters for class_1: (?). .....
>   ..... at
>   JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.js:22570)

Comment: Have you added ApplicantSvc to your modules, for instance app.module.js?

Comment: I already added that in app.module and it's working fine in other components which are AOT compiled. Only getting issue with JIT compiled component.

Comment: Found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789613/error-when-trying-to-use-a-service-in-dynamically-created-component-angular-5-1?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I've found that simply passing the service like a variable worked just fine

```
  this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
    .then((factories) => {
      const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
      this.cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);
      this.cmpRef.instance.name = 'my-dynamic-component';
      ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶v̶c̶.̶i̶n̶s̶e̶r̶t̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶c̶m̶p̶R̶e̶f̶.̶h̶o̶s̶t̶V̶i̶e̶w̶)̶;̶
      ... = .        
});
```